# Sharepoint 2007 ASP.NET web site integration

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2007

I have a asp.net web site that uses javascript and ajax calls.  Can this site be ported to sharepoint 2007? If so how is this done? Will SharePoint designer handle this?
TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your question seems to be too open ended. Short answer could be Yes it can be ported. However answering How in any single post may not be feasible. You may try searching and get some different alternatives.

I have known these two resources. See if you get more

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/ASPNET_to_Sharepoint.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjohnson/archive/2006/09/05/740498.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Like Subhash said the short answer is Yes. But you will have to decide whether its worth doing it. For example MOSS 2007 does not support ASP.net AJAX by default. you will have to manually install extensions.

One option is converting your ASP.net pages to user controls and view them using SharePoint pages or you can use Page Viewer WebPart to view your existing ASP.net pages.

Comment: Also look into updating the MOSS 2007 site to 3.5 web.config, there are multiple posts on how to do this and you'll get asp.net ajax that way as well.

Comment: I'm stuck with what the client has.